# Script for Azure Backup notifications

Tags: powershell, event-log

I's just a basic one, I am new to Powershell. Trying to get the statement below working.

```
$date = (Get-Date).AddDays(-1)

$currentdate = Get-Date -Format d

$check = Get-WinEvent -FilterHashtable @{LogName="CloudBackup";StartTime=$date;ID=3} *>$null

if ($check -eq $true) {
  Write-Host "`nOK: Azure Backup was successful on $currentdate"
  exit 0
} else {
  Write-Host "`nCritical: Problem with Azure Backup - $currentdate"
  exit 2
}
```

Specially `if ($check -eq $true)` doesn't seem to do what expected. As `$check` is checking for event ID 3 in the eventlog, if it's there it should return true, if not false. Unfortunately it's returning only false every time.

Could someone please advise? Is there a better way to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$check = Get-WinEvent ... *>$null
```

Your [redirection](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847746.aspx) is suppressing *all* output, so `$check` *always* has the value `$null`, which is [interpreted as `$false`](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/powershell/2006/12/24/boolean-values-and-operators/) in a boolean operation.

What you want to use is the [automatic variable](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847768.aspx) `$?` to check it if the last PowerShell operation was successful.

```
if ($?) {
  Write-Host "OK: Azure Backup was successful on $currentdate"
  exit 0
} else {
  Write-Host "Critical: Problem with Azure Backup - $currentdate"
  exit 2
}
```